# Express - get value of path matching string

Tags: node.js, express

### Question

I've got several nested routers, and would like to get access to the whole string that the request's path matched. It's a little hard to say with english, so take a look at this code:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const router1 = express.Router()
const router2 = express.Router()

// set up router 2 paths
router2.get('/path2/:param2', (req, res, next) => {
  const someVar = req.something // the value I'll talk about in a second
  return res.status(200).send({ someVar })
})

// set up router1 paths
router1.use('/path1/:param1', router2)

// connect the routers behind a base url
app.use('/api/v1', router1)

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

If I were to make a GET request with:

```sh
curl -X GET http://localhost:3000/api/v1/path1/myparam1/path2/myparam2
```

I want that to return an object like this:

```
{
  "someVar": "/api/v1/path1/:param1/path2/:param2"
}
```

### Context

I have middleware in my app which logs the path to an elasticsearch cluster, and I'd like the cluster to group paths by the string they used to match the request, rather than the request itself. That way I can get a visual of which request endpoints are being hit the most.

Answer (score 0):

```
// you need to set mergeParams: true on the router,
// if you want to access params from the parent router
var router1 = express.Router({mergeParams: true});
```

Comment: Ok! That's a great answer to part of the question. What would I log, then, if I wanted to get access to the parameter matching string? e.g. `/path1/:param1`?

Comment: you can get the original url using "req.url"

Comment: So in this case, if I implement the `mergeParams` option,  `req.url` would return `/api/v1/path1/myparam1/path2/myparam2` where I want the value used in express to match the path, `/api/v1/path1/:param1/path2/:param2`. Is there a way to get this without adding specialized middleware?

Comment: mergeParams in no specialized midlleware..you can use "req.url" to get the full request path and mergeParams option is to preserve the req.params values from the parent router.